# Can we bound $\frac{Cov(X,XY)}{Var(X)}$?

Tags: correlation, regression-coefficients, probability-inequalities

The question is can we bound $\beta = \frac{Cov(X,XY)}{Var(X)}$ with the help of the following assumptions :

- Y is a **positive bounded** random variable, let's assume $Y \in [0,1]$.
- X has an expectation of 1 and a finite variance.

I have this intuition that $\beta$ should be bounded in the same range as $Y$. As if we add the independence of X and Y. we get $\beta = E(Y) \in [0,1]$, or at least bounded..

Comment: Assume $Y=y$ is fixed, then $\beta(y)=\frac{y\textrm{Var}[X]}{\textrm{Var}[X]}=y$.

Answer (score 0):

It is easy to show that if $E(X^2Y)$ is bounded $\beta$ is also bounded.
But we also know $E(X^2Y)<E(X^2)<\infty$ for obvious reasons, there you go the boundness.

For better clarification. Since $Var(X)$ is finite, $\beta$ is bounded iff the $Cov(X,XY)=E(X^2Y)-E(X^2)E(Y)$ is bounded. $E(Y)<1$ and $E(X^2)=Var(X)+E(X)^2=Var(X)+1$. So the boundness is guaranteed if $E(X^2Y) $ is also granted.

Another interesting proof can also be generated by considering
$\beta=Corr(X,XY)Var(XY)<Var(XY)<Var(X)$